# Create a datetime string in Python for formatChecker()

Tags: python, jsonschema

How can I create a valid timestamp string of the current time in Python for `jsonschema.FormatChecker()`

The schema:

```
"foo": {"type": "string", "format": "datetime"},
```

Validate it:

```
validate(json, schema, format_checker=jsonschema.FormatChecker())
```

Comment: `str(datetime.datetime.now())`

Comment: that works, fyi it works with date-time not datetime